# add slash in last word using sed

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have the following command `cat urls.txt | sed 's/com/com\//'` which will add a slash in the last of url but the problem is whenever if there are other tlds like `net` and `org` it won't work, how I can make it to add the slash without specifying the tld

Tried to add a slash in url without to without specifying the tld

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` means "end of line" in sed regexes. Therefore,

```bash
sed 's=$=/='
```

will add a slash to each line's end.

Note that it uses a different delimiter than `/` to prevent the need of a backslash which improves readability.

Comment: And if there might be spaces or tabs at the end of line: `s=[[:blank:]]*$=/=`